# Search Blob and find multiple matches along with identity field

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, blob

I have an identity column and a string value stored as a blob in 2 columns in my db.

What I’m trying to do is search for multiple values within the string and return the results in different rows for each match.

For example:

```
ID   | String
1000 | ChrisBobTomSteve
```

I want to search the string for both Bob and Tom and return the results like this:

```
1000 | Bob
1000 | Tom
```

This is a simplified example but I have a very large db and I need to match on 39 different values to parse out the results so a union isn’t exactly efficient for this.

This is being done in oracle 11g.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Well if thoughts are greatly appreciated - I'd use a `CLOB` or `NCLOB` instead of a `BLOB`; that would make this a lot easier :) If you go with `CLOB` you can use a character function like `INSTR` to look for the values, or `REGEXP_LIKE` if you need to match on whole words only. With `BLOB` you don't have this kind of functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately the db structure is already set and I cant change that.  I just have to query from it.  To query for a single value, I can use the INSTR function though.  I'm just trying to see if there is a way I can capture multiple values without having to run my query 39 different times.  Thanks!